# Access to shared variable from inside Function

Tags: vb.net, dll

Code of my DLL:

```
Public Class DisaOJLibrary


    Public Shared log As StringBuilder

    Public Shared Function Test(PARAMS)
        DisaOJLibrary.log.Clear()
        DisaOJLibrary.log.Append("")

    The rest of the code....
```

When I call function Test() from my application it gives:
but I get `System.NullReferenceException`. The exception occurs on `DisaOJLibrary.log.Clear()` this line.

What am I doing wrong, how can I access variable from function declared in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declaring the variable log as Shared doesn't means that someone creates and initialize the object instance for you. You need to add

```
Public Shared Function Test(PARAMS)
    if DisaOJLibrary.log Is Nothing Then
       DisaOJLibrary.log = new StringBuilder()
    End if
    DisaOJLibrary.log.Clear()
    DisaOJLibrary.log.Append("")
    ....
```

or initialize it directly in the declaration at the class level

```
Public Shared log As StringBuilder = new StringBuilder
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that it was so easy. I was blaming classes for that.